# Как убрать недочеты сгенерированного PDF документа с помощью класса TCPDF для PHP?

Tags: corel-draw, pdf, tcpdf, php, svg

Добрый день, я с помощью класса TCPDF для PHP генерирую PDF файл из SVG изображения, на стороне сервера. Сначала были проблемы с русскими шрифтами, но их удалось решить и теперь все хорошо. Но возникла другая проблема - при открытии сгенерированного PDF в программе Corel Draw в левом нижнем углу есть замаскированная надпись "**Powered by TCPDF ([www.tcpdf.org](http://www.tcpdf.org))**" (она белого цвета и размером 1 пт).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ее убрать? Нужно сделать так, чтобы при генерации PDF документа этой надписи **не было**... (К сожалению, пока что информации не нашел!)

Вторая проблема состоит в том, что когда я открываю сгенерированный PDF документ в программе Corel Draw запрашиваются шрифты, которые использовались при генерации этого PDF документа. Как сделать так, чтобы при генерации **нужные шрифты встраивались** в PDF файл?

Comment: К сожалению, надпись **"Powered by TCPDF (www.tcpdf.org)"** из PDF файла убрать нельзя по условиям лицензионного соглашения...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, чтобы нужные шрифты не запрашивались, при генерации PDF вам нужно добавить эти шрифты в pdf файл методом addTTFfont

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, сейчас добавлю этот метод в свой код!